# Intersecting multiple points from CSV with multiple polygons using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3

I'm writing a script that imports many CSV files containing x and y coordinates from a specific folder and intersect each CSV file with each polygon from another folder. Example:
the csv_1, csv2, intersects with polygon1_, polygon_2...

I'm trying to write the code. I get all the layers without problems, but I don't know how to get intersection between them and how to write it in this code.

```
import glob, os, processing

output = 'C:/Users/Brubisgeo/Downloads/teste/csv/shp'
path_to_csv = 'C:/Users/Brubisgeo/Downloads/test/csv'
os.chdir(path_to_csv)

#Importing all the csvs from a folder and plotting: 

for fname in glob.glob('*csv'):
    filepath = os.path.join(path_to_csv, fname)
    uri = f'file:///{filepath}?type=csv&delimiter=%5Ct;&maxFields=10000&detectTypes=yes&xField=x&yField=y&crs=EPSG:31983&spatialIndex=no&subsetIndex=no&watchFile=no'
    name = fname.replace('.csv', '')
    lyr = QgsVectorLayer(uri,name, 'delimitedtext')
    QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(lyr)
    
    
#Importing all the polygons from a folder: 

path = 'D:/SCRIPTS/shps'
os.chdir(path)
layer = []
for root,directory,files in os.walk(path):
    for file in files: 
        if file.endswith('.shp'):
            full_path = os.path.join(root,file)
            vlayer = QgsVectorLayer(full_path,file[:-4],'ogr')
            b = QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(vlayer)

            #This is what I tried to do, create the lists (one from csvs files and another from polygons) but doesn't work. 

            for layers in layer:
                inter = {'INPUT':[lyr],'OVERLAY':[vlayer],'INPUT_FIELDS':[],'OUTPUT': (output+lyr+'_intersected.shp')
                processing.run('native:intersection',inter)
```

Comment: Sort the lists and zip: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1663807/how-do-i-iterate-through-two-lists-in-parallel